# Testing of Conditional Statement using Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When I run the test, it shows that only 1 test is passed. How to the test_function so that it shows that all the tests are passed.

Note that eval() function doesn't take any parameter.

```
import pytest

def eval():
    a=1  #got this value after calling some function (this can be 1,2,3 or any value)
    if a ==2:
        return 8
    elif a == 3:
        return 4
    else:
        return 42

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected", [
        (8),
        (4),
        (42),
    ])
def test_eval(expected):
    assert eval() == expected
```

Comment: Please, take a look on ["How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and try to reformat your post. The code snippet is difficult to read the way you posted it.

Comment: If the function doesn't take a parameter, you can't parametrize it. How does the `a =` value _actually_ get set?

Comment: I corrected it. Can you see the code now?

Comment: a is set after call a function.

Comment: `a` can not get set by another function if it's a local in `eval()`. Is it a global, perhaps?

Comment: Or let's suppose I can not change the eval() function. How to make a test using pytest.

Comment: Yes! `a` is a  global variable, my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after clarification in the comments, that `a` is a global... It would be better if it wasn't. :)

But if you can't change its signature,

```py
import pytest


def eval():
    if a == 2:
        return 8
    elif a == 3:
        return 4
    else:
        return 42


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_value, expected", [(2, 8), (3, 4), (4, 42)]
)
def test_eval(input_value, expected):
    global a
    a = input_value
    assert eval() == expected
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks @AKX. Cannot upvote you because I have less than 15 votes

Comment: Suppose if `a` is a local variable, how would the code change for the test script. if I use `a` as a local variable it only passes just 1 case test.

Comment: You can't modify a local variable from outside the function when it's not being executed. It would be better to pass it in as a parameter, `def eval(a):`.